# Create a static Circle/Pie chart in WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a Circle Chart in WPF/XAML. I have good experience in C# but I'm new in WPF.

The Circle needs to be cut in 3 parts and the same size each other, and each part will be filled with a color depending on on percentage, and without affecting the other parts. Please see the image in the link below for reference.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbqvewhl09kzypi/Circle%20Static%20Pie.png?dl=0

This is a very important project for me, I'll appreciate anybody help one this.

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28098/A-WPF-Pie-Chart-with-Data-Binding-Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Path section in this link if you want to draw it yourself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465055.aspx

The following is a quick mockup to get you started.

```
<Path StrokeThickness="15" Stroke="#FFEF8900" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="110,20,0,20" Data="M0,0 a1,1 0.5 0 1 0,180" />
            <Path StrokeThickness="15" Stroke="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="110,20,0,20" Data="M0,0 A1,1 30 0 0 0,180" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer, the real challenge for this is how to fill a part with a color but gradually... is this something you guys could help me?

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to do now. It's like three progress bars. Will the chart always be made up of three equal parts?